# Regex non-capturing groups being captured

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

> "/^(?:[A-Z]+)$/

And this string:

> TTT

And the output is:

> array (size=1)
>
> > 0 => string 'TTT' (length=3)

What's wrong? Can anyone point me to the good way doing this?

Comment: the first item of the array contains all that is matched in the string. capture groups starts at 1.

Comment: @WisdmLabs; Because there is one full match and no capture groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you match a string with `preg_match()`, `$matches[0]` will contain the entire matched string. The capturing group will be from `$matches[1]` onwards. In this case, your regex matched the string, so `$matches[0]` is filled with the whole matched string.

From the vastness of the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.